# How can I display the drillthough report from ASP.net from the ReportViewer DrillThrough event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reportviewer

I am trying to get the get the DrillThrough event to display the linked Report within the Final_GenralStatment_Total.rdlc report but instead I get the following error message:

"A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'."

Here is my ASP complete code page:

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms
```

Public Class FStatement
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub ReportViewer1_Drillthrough(sender As Object, e As DrillthroughEventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Drillthrough

    Try
        Dim report As LocalReport = CType(e.Report, LocalReport)
        'Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim adp As New INV_INDDataSetTableAdapters.Final_GSInterestTotalsTableAdapter
        Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try


End Sub
```

End Class

And the complete html page:

```
    <%@ Page Title="Final Statement" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="FStatement.aspx.vb" Inherits="Pension.FStatement" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    Final Statement
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana"
                    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)"
                    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"
                    ZoomMode="PageWidth" AsyncRendering="False" Height="100%"
                    ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True"
                    Width="100%" PageCountMode="Actual" BackColor="" ClientIDMode="AutoID" HighlightBackgroundColor="" InternalBorderColor="204, 204, 204" InternalBorderStyle="Solid" InternalBorderWidth="1px" LinkActiveColor="" LinkActiveHoverColor="" LinkDisabledColor="" PrimaryButtonBackgroundColor="" PrimaryButtonForegroundColor="" PrimaryButtonHoverBackgroundColor="" PrimaryButtonHoverForegroundColor="" SecondaryButtonBackgroundColor="" SecondaryButtonForegroundColor="" SecondaryButtonHoverBackgroundColor="" SecondaryButtonHoverForegroundColor="" SplitterBackColor="" ToolbarDividerColor="" ToolbarForegroundColor="" ToolbarForegroundDisabledColor="" ToolbarHoverBackgroundColor="" ToolbarHoverForegroundColor="" ToolBarItemBorderColor="" ToolBarItemBorderStyle="Solid" ToolBarItemBorderWidth="1px" ToolBarItemHoverBackColor="" ToolBarItemPressedBorderColor="51, 102, 153" ToolBarItemPressedBorderStyle="Solid" ToolBarItemPressedBorderWidth="1px" ToolBarItemPressedHoverBackColor="153, 187, 226" ShowBackButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False">
                    <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\Final_GenralStatment_Total.rdlc" EnableHyperlinks="True">
                        <DataSources>
                            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ODSFStatement" Name="DataSet" />
                        </DataSources>
                    </LocalReport>
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODSFStatement" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="Pension.INV_INDDataSetTableAdapters.Final_GenralStatment_TotalTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: So you want to load the target report with specific parameters into the report viewer. But how is your code (except maybe the first line) related to that goal?

Comment: There is no parameter in the sub report, I have the main report Final_GenralStatment_Total which displays the total with no issues, and I have a linked on a report field, if clicked it should fire the drill through event , displaying the sub report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to give this a try:

```
Protected Sub ReportViewer1_Drillthrough(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.DrillthroughEventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Drillthrough

    Dim lclRep As LocalReport = CType(e.Report, LocalReport)

    Dim adp As New Pension.INV_INDDataSetTableAdapters.Final_GSInterestTotalsTableAdapter
    Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", CType(adp.GetData(), DataTable))

    lclRep.DataSources.Add(rds)

End Sub
```

Also, you might want to have a look at this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-drillthrough-rdlc-report-with-parameters-reportviewer) (unfortunately using C#).

Comment: The ReportDataSource reported 6 overloads: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' is most specific for these arguments.

Comment: Ok, then what is the method that gets the DataTable with the report data?

Comment: There must be something about DataSetTableAdapters. But then I am getting the following error message "The report data source object must be of the type System.Data.DataTable, System.Collections.IEnumerable, or System.Web.UI.IDataSource".

Comment: Ok, then you should probably use `CType` to make it a `System.Data.DataTable`.

Comment: I did but back to the same error. "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'."

Comment: It's hard to tell not seeing your code. You have to create a new instance of `ReportDataSource` passing the name "Dataset1" (the name that was used when designing the second report) and a `DataTable` (containing the data for the second report) to the constructor. This instance has to be added to the `DataSources` collection of the report. Can you post the code of the last attempt?

Comment: I have updated the post to include the complete code and html page.

Comment: Your DataTable never gets filled. I updated my answer to show you what I meant.